# Immediate window stops updating on continuous running

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script with the For loop like this one:

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 to 200000
        'Some code
        Debug.print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

When i goes up to to some point the updating of the immediate window stops, whole application looks freezed without response until the 200000 loops are all done.

I have minimized my spreadsheets and disabled `ScreenUpdating` already.

In terms of successfully finishing a run there is no big deal but I think I should be able follow the progress, like giving me an idea when the run is going to finish. Current I use the `Wait` function between sections to allow the windows to update to get around the problem but I feel like this is a stupid way to do so... I think the system should be clever enough to allocate resources to update the windows...

Any better idea?

Comment: I have run your code and it looped 200k times with no errors/freezing at all.  The one thing i have changed is added `Option Explicit` and `dim i as Long` . Try adding these to you code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `Wait`, how about using `DoEvents`?

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want. Thanks.